# How can I force a compile error if a ref does not exist?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I was curious if there was a way to force the compile to fail if a ref was not already defined.  I do not want the ref to actually output anything into the document, but rather just check the existence condition.  For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
\begin{definition} \label{def C} \requires{def A} \requires{def B}
    A \underline{C} is an A and a B such that...  etc etc etc.
\end{definition}
```

and I do not want the `\requires{def A}` to actually produce output but just enforce that there was somewhere above a `\label{def A}`.  Ideally, you could use this for theorems and definitions.  This way I can just add any dependencies in my theorems/definitions and not have to worry about whether or not I already defined everything above, the compiler will tell me.  Does [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provide this?  If not, how hard would it be to add it?  I looked very briefly at the source code but I am not too familiar with the language so it would take me a while.

Comment: Usually just use `\PackageError{<package name>}{<Error message>}{<help text (simply keep empty)>}`

Comment: But the compiler already tells you if there were references that did not exist in the form of a warning: `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.`

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to enforce that the label is *before* the `\requires`, then you will have to redefine the `\label` command, as the current definition writes the label only to the `aux-files` and so its location relative to the `\ref` doesn't matter. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\Orilabel\label
\renewcommand\label[1]{\@namedef{mylabel@#1}{}\Orilabel{#1}}
\newcommand\require[1]{%
 \ifcsname mylabel@#1\endcsname
 \else
  \@latex@error{Reference #1 undefined}
 \fi}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\label{A}

\require{A}\require{B}

\ref{A},\ref{B} \label{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the sort of thing I am looking for...  Do I need to restore that 'at' with a \makeatother after the newcommand?

Comment: I'd wager you do ;)

Comment: @Tim: Yes you should use `\makeatother`. Nothing will explode if you forget it, but one should be orderly ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks!  The code seems to tell me my reference is undefined regardless of whether or not I put the label above.  When I get some more time I will investigate...  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!